# cascade list of class objects in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to parse a yaml file which contains cascaded data structures. Like

```
- Building
  Address
  Zip
  Room
   -- Employee1
   -- Employee2
```

etc.

I'm trying to store that in a list of class objects.
I've reduced the problem to following code:

`qstuff.py`

```
class bstuff():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b_name = ""
        self.b_port = ""

class astuff():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_name = ""
        self.a_port = ""
        self.a_st = [bstuff]
```

`worker.py`

```
from qstuff import astuff
from qstuff import bstuff

my_stuff = [astuff]

more_stuff = [bstuff]

more_stuff.append(bstuff)
more_stuff.append(bstuff)

my_stuff[0].a_st.append(bstuff)
```

this gives me following error:

```
$ python worker.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worker.py", line 11, in <module>
    my_stuff[0].a_st.append(bstuff)
AttributeError: class astuff has no attribute 'a_st'
```

I've searched for quite a while on the subject but couldn't find an understandable answer as to why this doesn't work or how I would need to store cascaded data in a list.

Comment: a_st would be a member, you are accessing it static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create any *instances*, you only created references to the classes.

You need to *call* a class to create an instance of that class:

```
self.a_st = [bstuff()]
```

and

```
my_stuff = [astuff()]
more_stuff = [bstuff()]
```

Your `astuff` class has no `a_st` attribute; that attribute is only set for instances in the `astuff.__init__` method (which is automatically called when a new instance is created).

I would not do this directly on classes (so don't add `a_st = [bstuff]` in the class body) unless you really want to create a hierarchy of mutable singleton classes for which you don't create instances.